# working with pointers Expression Must have class type error c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
>#include "stdafx.h"
>#include <Windows.h>
>#include <iostream>



using namespace std;


HANDLE pHandle;

class Player
{
public:
//Client Player
DWORD_PTR clientPlayer;
char Name[0x10];
unsigned int m_teamId;

//ClientControllableEntity
DWORD_PTR clientSoldier;
BYTE isOccluded;

//ClientSoldierReplication
DWORD_PTR clientReplication;
int state;

//LifeModule
DWORD_PTR healthcomponent;
FLOAT health;
};

class LocalPlayer : public Player
{
public:


DWORD_PTR VehicleVelocityA;
DWORD_PTR VehicleVelocityB;
DWORD_PTR VehicleVelocityC;
INT VehicleSpeed;

};

LocalPlayer lPlayer;

int readSpeed(LocalPlayer* localPlayer){
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(localPlayer->clientSoldier + 0x0280),     &localPlayer->VehicleVelocityA, sizeof(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityA), NULL);
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(localPlayer->clientSoldier + 0x0284), &localPlayer->VehicleVelocityB, sizeof(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityB), NULL);
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(localPlayer->clientSoldier + 0x0288), &localPlayer->VehicleVelocityC, sizeof(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityC), NULL);

double VelocityAX = pow(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityA.x, 2);
double VelocityBX = pow(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityB.x, 2);
double VelocityCX = pow(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityC.x, 2);

localPlayer->VehicleSpeed = 0;
localPlayer->VehicleSpeed = sqrt(VelocityAX + VelocityBX + VelocityCX) * 3.6f;
}
```

Can some one please help me with the above code? I'm getting expression must have class error at these lines

```
double VelocityAX = pow(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityA.x, 2);
double VelocityBX = pow(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityB.x, 2);
double VelocityCX = pow(localPlayer->VehicleVelocityC.x, 2);
```

it tells me local player must have a class type. Can some one help me debug this code its bugging me for hours.

Comment: What kind of variable type is `DWORD_PTR`?  Do you think it has a `.x` component?

Comment: can you explain a little more please im a newbie in c++

Comment: @DrewDormann, [Either `unsigned long` or `unsigned __int64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice to see you again, @chris.  I was *leading the horse* a bit with those two questions, given `DWORD_PTR VehicleVelocityA;` and at the error `VehicleVelocityA.x`.

Comment: @DrewDormann, If that means what I think it means, then sorry.

Answer (score 1):

DWORD_PTR is a pointer, not a structure. That is why it is giving an error.
`pow` function which expects `double` or `float`.

Declare `VehicleVelocityA` and other variables as `double` or `float` or a structure contains `x` as `double` or `float`.

Comment: can you please give me an example I have defined veichlevelocityA,B,C to Double but it still have the same error.

Comment: @greyjoy9025, If you mean `double`, it's still not a class type. Neither `DWORD_PTR`, nor `double`, have a member named `x` (or any other members, because they aren't classes).

Comment: @greyjoy9025 if you're still confused, perhaps you could explain what you think `.x` is doing in your code.  We don't know what you think that means, and neither does the compiler.

Comment: @greyjoy9025: simply remove `x` and just pass `vehiclevelocityA` to ` pow`.